# Why does my cream ale taste like a witbier?

Tags: flavor, off-flavor

Imagine my surprise when I opened a bottle of my [cream ale](http://www.northernbrewer.com/brewing/recipe-kits/extract-kits/extract-ale-kits/cream-ale-extract-kit.html) and found that it had picked up a clove-y flavor reminiscent of a wheat beer. It's not even presented as a risk in the [BJCP guidelines for cream ale](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style06.php#1a).

It's pretty clear that the flavor I'm tasting is [4-vinyl guaiacol](http://www.byo.com/stories/techniques/article/indices/19-brewing-tips/479-cloves-a-nut-browns-mr-wizard), but it's not clear where the heck it came from.

I used Safale S-05 dry yeast and fermented at a pretty steady 65°.

By the way, it's delicious.  I doubt I could replicate it, but I would if I could.

Comment: Clove flavors generally come from the yeast. What did you use? At what temperature did you ferment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I say let it age.  The kit you bought uses either WY1056 or Safale US-05 and both of them have a pretty clean profile.

My thoughts are this:  Either the beer is too young and that flavor will age out, or it was too warm when it fermented.

I gotta tell ya, sometimes these light flavored, light color beers can be the hardest.  On top of that, I've never had a cream ale that I would consider "typical of style".  They have all varied wildly. Big bad-assed beers with strong flavors and/or lots of hops can cover up a lot of tiny brewing technique refinements.

Let it age another month or two.  Give it a try then and see if the clove smell goes away.  Good luck with it.

Comment: I don't know if the batch will survive a month or two.  It's too tasty.  Thanks for the advice.  I think you're probably right.

Answer (score 2):

What yeast strain and fermentation temperature did you use?  Normally if you want a nice clean, low ester profile then you pitch lots of yeast, ferment on the cool side (64-65ºF) and use a clean ale strain like 1056/WLP001.

Answer (score 2):

Did you dechlorinate your water, or use a bleach sanitizing solution? This can cause chlorophenols which can cause a clove flavour.  I just brewed an ESB with Whitelabs Brit ale yeast.  I  didn't dechlorinate and used bleach to sanitize, and I have slight clove with banana nose, and I thought pretty tasty Belgian!  Brit ale yeasts are higher in phenols so hard to tell brewing flaws from yeast.

Comment: Its funny how quickly a British beer can turn "Belgian" on you.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old topic, however, I have a cream ale that I recently bottled about a month ago and I have been enjoying. Last night I serve it to a friend and and he said he tasted a faint taste of cloves. I missed it. The thing I found in common was that we each brewed with safale #5. Have you used that yeast since? If so, what do you think of your brews since?

Comment: I've used US-05 quite a bit since, but never had this flavor again. Others didn't detect it like I did, so I think I'm very sensitive to this compound.... Or it was an infection.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that it's an infection.  Time will tell.

Comment: It was an infection, most likely. One of the rare delicious ones. I guess they have to happen from time to time.

Comment: I agree time will tell